# Org Chart in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, organization-chart

I would like to make a flowchart representing the organizational structure of the members of the company in SharePoint Online. I tried using Plumsail Org Chart Web part. I followed the installation steps, but I encountered an error at end.

Please, help me solve this problem or suggest other solutions.

This is the link for the Plumnsail Org chart: http://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/

[image]

Comment: can you, please mention what the error says in English? I can't read what it says on the screenshot.

Comment: this file does not contain an associated application to perform this action. install an eapplication or, if it is already done create an association on the application settings page by default     thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here are the suggestions

- Check that you have download the package for the right version of SharePoint. You need Office 365 version: "**SharePoint Online (Office 365)**"
- Do not double-click the sppkg. This is not an installation program and that's not going to be installed by doing so. Instead, follow the instructions [on their website](http://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/docs/orgchart-installation-office-365-v3/)

> Org Chart is a SharePoint Framework add-in that allows you to
>   visualize organization structure on both classic and modern SharePoint
>   pages. Unfortunately, SharePoint Store doesn’t support the
>   installation of SharePoint Framework add-ins. That is why you need to
>   install add-in manually.
>
> You have to be a SharePoint administrator to complete the
>   installation. If you don’t see some menus from the instruction below,
>   most likely you are not a SharePoint administrator. Please contact
>   your administrator to assist with the installation.

Open Office 365 admin center:

[image]

- Navigate to SharePoint Admin Center:

[image]

- Go to ‘Apps’ classic feature:

[image]

- Open App Catalog

[image]

- Open App Catalog
- If you don’t have ‘App Catalog’ yet, you will be able to create a new one:

[image]

Just fill in ‘Title’, ‘Web Site Address’, ‘Administrator’ and ‘Storage Quota’ and click ‘OK’. For example:

- Title – App Catalog Site
- Web Site address – AppCatalog
- Administrator – Fill in your account name
- Storage Quota – 10 GB

[image]

Navigate to ‘Apps for SharePoint’ and upload Add-in package that you downloaded at the beginning of this instruction (you need to upload to the App Catalog the whole .sppkg file without unpacking it):

[image]

Upload App To Catalog
You need to select “Make this solution available to all sites in the organization” in the dialog. Once you did this you can add a web part to a page.

[image]

If you don’t want to make this app availalbe on all sites, you will need to add app to each site manually.

Adding web part to a page
Navigate to the page where you want to add an org chart.

Note: If you use “Classic” SharePoint pages follow this instruction to add web part to a page.

Pick ‘Plumsail Org Chart’ web part from the menu to add it to your page:

Add Modern Org Chart WebPart

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a Windows problem, when users run third-party programs or open files.

It happens when "IsShortcut" string value for LNK filetype is missing in Windows Registry.

Please refer to the below article to fix this issue:

https://www.askvg.com/this-file-does-not-have-a-program-associated-with-it-error-message-while-running-a-game-from-game-explorer-in-windows-vista/